# Detect whether there's space before and after macro

Tags: spacing, macros

My document has a custom macro called

```
\newcommand{\myparenthetical}[1]{[#1]}
```

However, I want to be sure that in the document I always have a single space before and after the macro.

I would like

```
This\myparenthetical{9}is a\myparenthetical{10} test.
```

to appear as

> This [9] is a [10] test.

*not* as

> This[9]is a[10] test.

How would I do this with a macro?

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\myparenthetical}[1]{ [#1] }` but you'll get problem with periods: `foo\myparenthetical{10}.`

Comment: If you want spaces, add them when typing in the document. I'm not sure what would be the purpose of using bad input for fixing it later. What if punctuation follows? There would be too many case to distinguish.

Comment: you'd also need to detect the beginning of a paragraph, in the (probably vanishingly small) case where `\myparenthetical` comes as the first thing.  really, keying a space before is more trustworthy.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\unskip` removes previous space. Depending on the mode this is horizontal or vertical space. Spaces after the command can be ignored by `\ignorespaces`. A space token can be set by `\space` and `\@ifnextchar` tests for following tokens to avoid space setting, if a punctuation character follows. As side effect it also removes following spaces.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myparenthetical}[1]{%
  \ifhmode
    \unskip
    \space
  \fi
  [#1]%
  \@ifnextchar{.}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{,}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{;}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{!}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{?}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{)}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar\par{}{%
    \space
    \ignorespaces
  }}}}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\myparenthetical{1} starts a sencents and ends it \myparenthetical{2}.
\myparenthetical{3}Lorem ipsum\myparenthetical{4} ,\myparenthetical{5}.

This\myparenthetical{6}is \myparenthetical{7} a\myparenthetical{8} test.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Simplification

The example can be simplified by using package `xspace`, thanks Barbara.
However, `\xspace` cannot be used directly, because it is intended for macros without arguments. Then the scanning for the macro name would swallow the next space. But `\xspace` is fine for punctuation detection. Thus the following space can be gobbled by the following `\romannumeral` trick, where the space is consumed by the character constant and the resulted negative number is then removed by `\romannumeral`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myparenthetical}[1]{%
  \ifhmode
    \unskip
    \space
  \fi
  [#1]%
  \expandafter\xspace\romannumeral-`\x
}

\begin{document}
\myparenthetical{1} starts a sencents and ends it \myparenthetical{2}.
\myparenthetical{3}Lorem ipsum\myparenthetical{4} ,\myparenthetical{5}.

This\myparenthetical{6}is \myparenthetical{7} a\myparenthetical{8} test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: how does this differ from `\xspace` for the following space?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good hint, I have updated the answer. The difference in the normal use case of `\xspace` is that `\myparenthetical` has an argument, thus that the space afterwards is not ignored.

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting some strange behavior when coupling this with `svmono.cls` style sheet. For example, your `\xspace` solution has a trailing "x" after each parenthetical, e.g.: [123]x

Comment: @Geremia Probably a copy & paste error. The characters after `\romannumeral` are `-` (hyphen, U+002D),  back tick (U+0060), backslash (U+005C) and the letter `x` (U+0078). Another way of breaking is inside moving arguments, the command is not robust. It can be fixed by using `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.